# Calling .getElementsByTagName('tbody') returns thead

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Here's an interesting complication I ran across today: calling for tbody tags returns the thead as well.

First the code:

```
function GetAnchors(){
if(!document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ2')){
    return;
};
var item = document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ2').getElementsByTagName('table');
if(!item[0]){
    return;
}
try{
item = item[0].firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.getElementsByTagName('table');
item = item[0].getElementsByTagName('tbody');
item = item[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(i=0; i<item.length; i++){
    if(item[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].hasAttribute("height")){
        item[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].firstChild.innerHTML = Hijack( item[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].firstChild.innerHTML);
    }
}
}catch(err){
    return;
}
```

}

The ne'er line of code:

`item = item[0].getElementsByTagName('tbody');`

I have tested, so this works:

`item = item[1].getElementsByTagName('tbody');`

So it returns the thead element with the tbody.

For those of you who picked it up, yes this is SharePoint.(2013)  The browser is IE10 in compatability mode IE9.

I have this on several pages, and it works as intended with the exception of one, there's no significant differences in the html's structure (i.e. the table and cell structure is the same, just different text within.)

I'm just curious, has anyone ever seen this?  Or better yet some documentation?

Or is this just IE?

Comment: Can we see the HTML ? A fiddle maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your interest, but I figured it out.

Apparently, in SharePoint 2013 (probably 2010 as well) Assigned To Column headers are created as tables:

```
<div class="ms-vh-div" name="AssignedTo" SortFields="" ResultType="" FieldType="User" DisplayName="Assigned To" CTXNum="7" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable="">
<table dir="none" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-imnImgTD"><img id="imnhdr7" onload="IMNRegisterHeader(event)" border="0" alt="" src="" width="12" height="12" valign="middle" altbase="Presence enabled for this column">
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vh ms-imnTxtTD" noWrap="">
                <a id="diidSort7AssignedTo" class="ms-headerSortTitleLink" onfocus="OnFocusFilter(this)" onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript: " SortingFields=""><img class="ms-hidden" border="0" alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="" width="1" height="1"></a>
                <img border="0" alt="" src="">
                <img border="0" alt="" src="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hence, it was returning the tbody within the thead.

This may sound obvious, but it's nested pretty deep.

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Item[0] was returning the <thead> object itself in the debugger, so it wasn't immediately obvious.  Anyhow, thanks again.